# How do I group a table of datetimes together as long as there is a continuous chain at least every hour?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'events'.

It contains eventID (INT), eventDateTime(DATETIME), and eventMessage(VARCHAR).

I want to be able group the rows by eventDateTime where there is another row with eventDateTime within 1 hour each side. This should propogate forever (for example a group should be able go on for years, as long as there is never a gap longer than an hour between a linking chain of eventDateTime values within that time period. Ideally I want to end up selecting MIN(eventID) for each group, and both the MIN and MAX of eventDateTime which will give me the time span in which the group runs.

I assume I need some kind of iterating loop to do this? Where would I start?

Comment: Iterating loops aren't real SQL, it's set based ;-)

Comment: This is a 'sequence starts and ends' problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from subqueries we need

```
SET @row_number1 = 0;
SET @row_number2 = 0;
```

The query returns us the events table ordered with row numbers (rn)

```
SELECT 
    (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) AS rn, eventID, eventDateTime
FROM
    events
ORDER BY eventDateTime
```

Let's mar them as SUB1 and SUB2

Then let's join them

```
select *
from SUB1 join SUB2 on sub1.rn=sub2.rn+1
```

So we have in one row 2 eventDateTime of current and next row and can calculate time difference

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, SUB1.eventDateTime, SUB2.eventDateTime) as hoursDiff
```

Then we can add `HAVING hourDiff>1` to have rule breaking intervals. For such records SUB1.eventDateTime is the end of previous group but SUB2.eventDateTime is the beginning of next group.

So our query will return us

```
SUB1.eventID as previousGroupEndEventId,
SUB1.eventDateTime as previousGroupEndeventDateTime,
SUB2.eventID as currentGroupStartEventId,
SUB2.eventDateTime as currentGroupStarteventDateTime,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, SUB1.eventDateTime, SUB2.eventDateTime) as breakInterval
```

And you can use the query results to get all your info

Answer (score 0):

For complex problems requiring some form of looping, some databases allow recursive queries, but apparently not mysql.

Fortunately, in your case I don't think it is necessary. You can instead look for any rows which don't have another row in the preceeding hour thus:

```
select *
from events as A
where not exists (
  select 1
  from events as B
  where B.eventDateTime <  A.eventDateTime 
  and  B.eventDateTime > DATE_ADD(A.eventDateTime, INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
  )
```

Example kept simple. Fix up the details to meet your requirements.
Working example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3b73c/1